Insertions in the amida from Rosh Hashanah to Yom kipur
In the gemera brachos 34a it says one is not to make any additions to prayer in the first three and last three brachos of the amida. This is also brought down in rambam in chapter 1 of tefila and birchas kohanim that one should never change or add anything to the first and last three blessings yet we common practice is to make additions in these places and even in ch. 2 of tefila and birchas kohanim the rambam goes on to say many people are accustomed to making these additions.
Why are these allowed and how did they come to be part of the amida?

We make changes in the last three blessings every Rosh Chodesh

mentioning Rosh chodesh was instituted by the chachamim who also created the rules for what may or may not be changed in the amida see brachos 29a

Maybe, but point is your summaries aren't very precise. If you don't write precisely don't be surprised if the rules don't always make sense.

@DoubleAA the question is written clearly enough to be understood and the rules created by chazal have nothing to do with how I worded my question.

Well, if it is indeed "clearly enough to be understood" then I'm sure you won't get any answers that you need to comment on to follow up with to better explain the question. Because the question is already clear enough.

@DoubleAA sounds like you need to learn how to read and look at the sources instead of just making assumptions

See the Meiri (here) for one answer.

The Gemoro you quote  says:

One must never request his own needs in the first three or in the
last three blessings; rather, he should do so in the middle blessings.

The implication is that the needs of everyone can be mentioned in the first and last three. This is explicit in Shulchan Oruch O Ch 112 (1) who says:

אל ישאל אדם צרכיו בג' ראשונות ולא בג' אחרונות ודוקא צרכי יחיד אבל צרכי
צבור שרי:
“A person should not ask for his needs in the first three [blessings]
nor in the last three [blessings of the Amidah prayer] but asking for the needs of the community is permissible.”


in regards to the Gemara true but only because the gemera says requests. seemingly because normally an individual would be adding personal requests during the amidah but the way this is brought down in rambam does not make a distinction about the type of addition " וְשָׁלֹשׁ רִאשׁוֹנוֹת וְשָׁלֹשׁ אַחֲרוֹנוֹת לְעוֹלָם אֵין מוֹסִיפִין בָּהֶן וְלֹא פּוֹחֲתִין מֵהֶן וְאֵין מְשַׁנִּין בָּהֶן דָּבָר"

@Dude "לעולם אין מוסיפים בהן" I guess the Rambam didn't hold of yaaleh veyavo on rosh chodesh

@Dude Note another answer is that the additions in the beginning of amidah aren’t requests but rather praises of Gd (“you remember us in the book of life” etc) and therefore they’re permitted. But in the ending of amidah requests are allowed so we do indeed insert them (“write us for a good life” etc)

Sefaria translates זָכְרֵֽנוּ לְחַיִּים
as Remember us for life not as you remember us.
